# Angular ng-options to ng-repeat with extra options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have a `<select>` element and I use `ng-options` to add insert available values, my code is like

```
<select ng-model="selectedCollection"
    ng-options="collection.collectionName for collection in seriesCollection">
</select>
```

This works fine, and in `$scope.selectedCollection` I have the whole `collection` object.

Now I need to add some extra `<option>` elements based on some parameters. I think the best way is avoid using `ng-options` and do something like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedCollection"
    <option value='c1' ng-if="case1">somevalue</option>
    <option value='c2' ng-if="case2">somevalue2</option>
    <option ng-repeat="collection in seriesCollection">
        {{ collection.collectionName }}
    </option>
    <option value='c3' ng-if="case3">somevalue3</option>
</select>
```

This way `selectedCollection` contains a string named c1, c2 or c3 when a "static" option is selected, but I would like it to contain the whole `collection` object when one of them is selected.

I tried with `<option ng-repeat="collection in seriesCollection" value="{{ collection }}">` but then the stored value is not the `collection` object but a string representing it's serialization. How can I do?

Comment: Try `ng-value` in your option.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, this way the `selectedCollection` variable contains a string value like this `"[object Object]"`, not the "real" `collection` object

Comment: if you use ng-repeat to create the options then the model will be a string, to achieve object binding you would need to use ng-options

Comment: Ok thank you @maurycy , so a mix as I'm doing can't be done... Maybe I can add a `selectedCollectionName` variable as `ng-model` and link a function to `ng-change` that actually compute `selectedCollection` based on the name... It's the best solution I can find

Comment: @maurycy can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you try to achieve can't be done.
It is the `ngOptions` directive that takes care of binding the object to model and any other method like `ngRepeat` will set model as string therefore value can't be object and mixing `ngOptions` with html `option` will not work.

You can utilise `ngChange` or add the cases to the collections and use filter to return only the one that should be displayed